# WCF Endpoint address without port number

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service without port numbers in the endpoint address. I want to know how the ports are assigned?

**Service Endpoint**

```
<services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="CalServiceBehavior" name="Test.Services.CI.Cal1Service">
      <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding" name="Cal1Service" contract="Test.Services.Cal1.ICal1Service" />                
   </service>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="CalServiceBehavior" name="Test.Services.CI.Cal2Service">
      <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding" name="Cal2Service" contract="Test.Services.Cal2.ICal2Service" />        
   </service>
</services>
```

**Client Endpoint**

```
<client>
    <endpoint name="cal1" address="net.tcp://100.100.11.4/Test.Services.Cal1/Cal1Service.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding" contract="Test.Services.Cal1.ICal1Service"/>
    <endpoint name="cal2" address="net.tcp://100.100.11.4/Test.Services.Cal2/Cal2Service.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding" contract="Test.Services.Cal2.ICal2Service"/>
</client>
```

Comment: If you don't specify them, they'll be assigned automatically.  This will vary depending on how you're hosting the service.  Normal ports are 80/443 (http/https), 808 (net.tcp), etc.

Comment: Added tcp binding for the service. TCP - 808:*   How are ports assigned on the client side?

Comment: I need to open port for firewall on the client side. What ports are assigned?